# Filterout empty value from objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a dataset like this:

```
let data = {
 "00:00": [],
 "00:30": ["123"],
 "01:00: ["4560", "123"],
 "01:30": [],
 ...
 "23:30": []
}
```

Now I would like to filterout those key from object whose value is not empty array.

I tried using object.key method but it will return the key name. I want key with value.

What I did is like:

```
let result = Object.keys(data).filter(o => data[o].length > 0);
console.log(result)
```

this will return the result:

```
["00:30", "01:00"]
```

what I expect is

```
[{"00:30": ["123"]}, {"01:00": ["4560", "123"]}]
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: do you really need only one key in an object as result?

Comment: Your code works fine.I just checked.You just missed apostrophe " on third data in object.("01:00)

Answer (score 1):

You could get the entries, filter by length and build a new object.

```js
let data = { "00:00": [], "00:30": ["123"], "01:00": ["4560", "123"], "01:30": [], "23:30": [] },
    result = Object.fromEntries(Object
        .entries(data)
        .filter(({ 1: { length } }) => length)
    );

console.log(result);
```